# Selecting single column where multiple columns match.

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which has multiple columns that have an ID, and I need to get information from one column wherever it matches.

```
tblA

colA | colB | colC | colD
1       5      6      7
2       5      5      8
3       7      8      9
4       8      8      9
```

Is there a way that I can Select column A where column b, column c, and column d all equal a number but keep them in their columns?

Basically if I'm looking for "5" is on table a columns b,c, and d it will return the following:

```
colB | colC | colD
1       2
2
```

Comment: Stared at this a bit...no idea how you obtain column c with a 2...might need more explanation?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 colC has a 5 in it, so it will return the 2 from colA for colC

Comment: @Joshm ok but why do the 1 and the 2 appear in the same row in the result?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I understand it as a rank().

Comment: @McNets if it's a rank, why do we see a 2 (and not 1) in columnC that has only a single 5 value? Question is unclear. Voting to close, until it is edited and questions clarified.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ second row ?

Answer (score 1):

Does this cover your expected result?

> ```
> create table tblA(id int, colA int, colB int, colC int, colD int);
> insert into tblA values
> (1, 1, 5, 6, 7),
> (2, 2, 5, 5, 8),
> (3, 3, 7, 8, 9),
> (4, 4, 8, 8, 9);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 4 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select sum(iif(colA=5, 1, 0)) over (order by id) colA,
>        sum(iif(colB=5, 1, 0)) over (order by id) colB,
>        sum(iif(colC=5, 1, 0)) over (order by id) colC,
>        sum(iif(colD=5, 1, 0)) over (order by id) colD
> from   tblA
> where  colA=5 or colB=5 or colC=5 or colD=5;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> colA | colB | colC | colD
> ---: | ---: | ---: | ---:
>    0 |    1 |    0 |    0
>    0 |    2 |    1 |    0
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=afd9f821c2ce4264f7e6f67c7556838b)*

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having a result like this instead:

```
colB | colC | colD
1      NULL   NULL
2      2      NULL
```

This query would do the trick for the number 5:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN colB = 5 THEN ColA ELSE NULL END as colB,
CASE WHEN colC = 5 THEN ColA ELSE NULL END as colC,
CASE WHEN colD = 5 THEN ColA ELSE NULL END as colD
FROM YourTable yt
WHERE yt.colB = 5 OR yt.colC = 5 OR yt.colD = 5
```

Now, if you want that 2 in colC in the first row, I'm out of ideas on how to put it there, sorry.